# Xamarin Android ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: android, xamarin

since updating Xamarin Android to 9.2 on mac OS Catalina i got this exception

Exception in `base.oncreate()`

> [MonoDroid] System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Exception
>   of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' was thrown.
>   [MonoDroid] Type 'callback_factory__class' is not finished [MonoDroid]
>   at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.GetTypes (System.Boolean
>   exportedOnly) [0x0012d] in <6de48997d0c0445dbea8d4d83492d8c6>:0

Any ideas ?

Thx

Comment: You might wanna update all your packages!!!

Comment: updating all packages does not work

Comment: Try to delete the `obj` and `bin` file,and restart.